# Error Submitting My App to the App Store

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I have setup my App Buddle ID in the Provisioning Portal. (I am NOT using any wildcards in the name.) I have been able to successfully generate provisioning certificates and have run my app on my device and have even distributed via Ad-Hoc already. However, when I then go into iTunes Connect, (or using the Application Loader), I click on "Manage Your Applications" and then I add my company name and hit Next... and then I get the message "You have no eligible Bundle IDs for iOS apps. To register one click here." The "here" links back over to the Provisioning Portal where I see my Bundle ID. It's like the Portal and iTunes Connect aren't in sync. This has been going on for about two weeks now. Several others have reported this error but none of the suggested solutions I have read work for me. It's a free app so I don't need a paid contract or anything. iTunes Connect shows that all is good on the contract and banking side of things.

I have been unable to get any resolution on this from Apple. (I've called the Developer Support line and posted on the Apple Developer Forum. TWICE!) Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you create an app on iTunesConnect, you must create an AppId on the Provisioning Portal. Note that if you have already used an AppId (even if you deleted the app), you won't be able to use the same AppId again.

Try creating another AppId and using it to create your app on iTunesConnect.

Comment: Thanks Fbafelipe! While I had already created the AppId on the Provisioning Portal I had NOT tried just simply adding a new AppId. I did as you suggested and that worked. Thanks again!